# Properties of determinants for invertible matrix $n \times n$.

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

It is known that if an $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is invertible, then $\det(A^{-1})=1/\det(A)$.

My question is, does this work both ways? Does $\det(A) = 1/\det(A^{-1})$?

Comment: Yes since the inverse of $A^{-1}$ is $A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property of an inverse matrix $A^{-1}$ of a matrix $A$ is
$$
A A^{-1} = A^{-1} A = I
$$
where $I$ is the identity matrix.
You can now take the determinant of both sides of the equation, e.g.:
$$
\det(A A^{-1}) = \det(I)
$$
For the left side we can make use of the multiplicity of the determinant, the right side yields 1:
$$
\det(A) \det(A^{-1}) = 1
$$
For invertible matrices both matrices must have a non-zero determinant, so you can divide both sides by $\det(A^{-1})$ and infer:
$$
\det(A) = 1 / \det(A^{-1})
$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x, y \neq 0$, we have $x = 1/y \iff xy =1 \iff y = 1/x$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can either write A as $(A^{-1})^{-1}$ or just treat $A^{-1}$ as $A$ (switch the roles) and get the desired outcome.